# moving from hot-reloader to react-refresh in office add-in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, office-addins, react-hot-loader

I am trying to use react-refresh instead of react hot reloader, which comes with the standard set up of `yo office generator`.

I tried to follow tutorials like [this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-fast-refresh-the-new-react-hot-reloader-652c6645548c) but to no avail. Either my app stopped reloading or my dev-server was unable to start.
The current mentions of hot reloader are mainly in the `webpack.config.js` and in the `index.js` files. Those files are basically still the same as they came out of the `yo office generator`

```
// index.js
import App from "./components/App";
import { AppContainer } from "react-hot-loader";
import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/font-icons-mdl2";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
/* global document, Office, module, require */

initializeIcons();

let isOfficeInitialized = false;

const title = "Contoso Task Pane Add-in";

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("container")
  );
};

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.onReady(() => {
  isOfficeInitialized = true;
  render(App);
});

/* Initial render showing a progress bar */
render(App);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./components/App", () => {
    const NextApp = require("./components/App").default;
    render(NextApp);
  });
}
```

webpack:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const urlDev = "https://localhost:3000/";
const urlProd = "https://www.contoso.com/"; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PRODUCTION DEPLOYMENT LOCATION

async function getHttpsOptions() {
  const httpsOptions = await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions();
  return { cacert: httpsOptions.ca, key: httpsOptions.key, cert: httpsOptions.cert };
}

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "core-js", "@fluentui/react"],
      taskpane: ["react-hot-loader/patch", "./src/taskpane/index.js"],
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.js",
    },
    output: {
      clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          use: [
            "react-hot-loader/webpack",
            {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              options: {
                presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
              },
            },
          ],
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
          generator: {
            filename: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: "assets/*",
            to: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
          {
            from: "manifest*.xml",
            to: "[name]" + "[ext]",
            transform(content) {
              if (dev) {
                return content;
              } else {
                return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["taskpane", "vendor", "polyfill"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["commands"],
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Promise: ["es6-promise", "Promise"],
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      https: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
    },
  };

  return config;
};
```

I already tried to follow the aforementioned tutorial, but I don't seem to find a way to completely migrate.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `if (module.hot) {` try removing this block?

Answer (score 1):

Try the documentation on the git repo - https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin

Update the webpack config to use react-refresh-plugin similar to below code.

```
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');


rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {
          plugins: [dev && require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')].filter(Boolean),
        },
      },
    ],
  },
],
```

Comment: I think the information above should be the accepted answer. I have updated an office addin repo that I expect was an ejected CRA using the ancient `react-hot-loader` to `react-refresh`, just following the instructions in the repo linked above.